# grails remoteField javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I'm having trouble returning a value to the view which then decides if the Submit button should be selectable or not. I'm checking the value of accNbr against an api call that returns JSON. I simple want to not if the user is found or not.

A snippet from within my form on my view - here is the account number input:

```
<g:remoteField paramName="accNbr" action="validateCustomer" update="[failure: 'error']" bean="${accNbrInstance}"  required="" size='40' name="accNbr" value="${accNbr}" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-regexp="[0-9]{12}" data-regexp-message="This field requires a valid Account Number of 12 digits"/>
```

then I have JS (which I think has the errors:

```
function accountNoError(){

    if($('#accountValid').html().value = "Not found"){
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#clear_btn').show();
    }else{
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    }

}
```

and my controller function:

```
def validateCustomer() {

    def accountNo = params.accNbr
    //def accountNo = "621137093178"
    def accountValid

    if(accountNo.length() == 12){
        def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://my.API.call/' + accountNo)
        http.auth.basic ('username','password')
        http.request(GET, ContentType.JSON) { req ->
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
                accountValid = json
                print("JSON is: " + json)
                println("Valid Account")
            }
        }
    }else {
        accountValid = "Not found"
        println("Invalid Account")
    }

    return accountValid
}
```

Comment: I don't get accountvalid in my view and so the submit button is clickable

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery you have an if...else statement.

In your `if` you disable your submit button:

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
```

and in your `else` you disable your submit button:

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
```